# SMS reply not being received

Tags: sms, twilio, reply

I set up a basic Twilio app 2 weeks ago that receives certain keywords and returns relevant info.

This was all working fine until a day or so ago, now if I send a message I get no reply. Yet when I check my twilio log it shows the message being received and the reply as being sent (and Im being billed for the replies).

If I open the relevant webpage and send the data across manually I get the response expected so I know the code behind is doing as it should. Plus as I say, this was working and suddenly stopped without any changes to code taking place.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You can look into the Twilio logs: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/logs, is this a test account? Which language? US number? More details will help

Comment: I have checked the logs and all appear to be fine ie it shows the messages received and then being replied to. Its a full account with a UK voice/SMS number

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. This sounds like something our help team can assist you with. It would be best to email help@twilio.com and share some message SIDs that exhibit the behaviour you've described and they will help you out.